# Implement CustomAdapter to Fragment ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter, custom-adapter

i'm attemp to implement CustomAdapter on Fragment and ListView, but it show an error NullPointerException in `androidListView.setAdapter(androidListAdapter);`

Previously I tried CustomAdapter without fragment, and it was a success

This is my Fragment Code :

```
public class LaporanFragment extends Fragment {
private ArrayAdapter<String> mLaporanAdapter;
String androidListViewStrings[] = {"Android ListView Example", "Android Custom ListView Example", "Custom ListView Example",
        "Android List Adapter", "Custom Adapter ListView", "ListView Tutorial",
        "ListView with Image and Text", "Custom ListView Text and Image", "ListView Custom Tutorial"};

Integer image_id[] = {R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
        R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
        R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher};

public LaporanFragment(){
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_laporan, container, false);
    LaporanAdapter androidListAdapter = new LaporanAdapter(getActivity(), image_id, androidListViewStrings);
    ListView androidListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_view_laporan);
    androidListView.setAdapter(androidListAdapter); **//Error nullPointerExeption on this line**

    return rootView;
}}
```

And this is my Custom Adapter Code :

```
public class LaporanAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
String[] androidListViewStrings;
Integer[] imagesId;
Context context;

public LaporanAdapter(Activity context, Integer[] imagesId, String[] textListView) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item_laporan, textListView);
    this.androidListViewStrings = textListView;
    this.imagesId = imagesId;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View viewRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_laporan, null,
            true);
    TextView mtextView = (TextView) viewRow.findViewById(R.id.list_item_laporan_textview);
    ImageView mimageView = (ImageView) viewRow.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    mtextView.setText(androidListViewStrings[i]);
    mimageView.setImageResource(imagesId[i]);
    return viewRow;
}}
```

UPDATE :

Logcat Output :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
          Process: id.co.gloftech.pelaporandishub, PID: 4859
          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{id.co.gloftech.pelaporandishub/id.co.gloftech.pelaporandishub.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
              at id.co.gloftech.pelaporandishub.LaporanFragment.onCreateView(LaporanFragment.java:85)
              at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2087)
              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1113)
              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1295)
              at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1682)
              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:607)
              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:181)
              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)
              at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6006)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

And the fragment_laporan.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity$LaporanFragment">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/list_view_forecast"></ListView>
```

Comment: Show the logcat output and `fragment_laporan.xml` code.

Comment: @KNeerajLal thanks, i have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the `ListView` id wrong. So `rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_view_laporan)` will return `null` and lead to an NPE.

Change,

```
ListView androidListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_view_laporan);
```

to,

```
ListView androidListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_view_forecast);
```